# Jersey REST service

Tags: rest, jersey

Am using Jersey 1.19 for a REST service..

The URL pattern in `web.xml` is:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In the Java class am using a method which is doing a kind of redirect to another page saved in a web folder. It looks fine up to the point when I call a specific resource:

```
http://localhost:8084/userProfile/rest/user
```

This should redirect to:

```
http://localhost:8084/userProfile/signup/index.jsp
```

but it redirects to:

```
http://localhost:8084/userProfile/rest/signup/index.jsp
```

Which normally doesn't exist.

The method in the Java Class:

```
@Path("/user")
public class userProfile {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Response returnForm() throws URISyntaxException {
        URI uri = new URI("/signup/index.jsp");
        return Response.temporaryRedirect(uri).build();
    }
}
```

How can I avoid redirection to a URL including `/rest/`?

Comment: Can you redirect it to [http:''localhost:8084/userProfile/signup/index.jsp]
 building the prefix from the request URL?

Comment: Yes, I already tried this and it works fine.. but I would prefer if I can use the relative path to the signup/index.jsp. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is/was really simple... the Path should go one step back to
avoid the url-pattern /rest/*:

```
 ....
 URI uri = new URI("../signup/index.jsp");
 ...
```

Thx!